# Why doesn't in-app purchase show my application's name when testing in the sandbox?

Tags: iphone

I have completed in app purchase for my application. Its working fine.
The only problem i have , when i test in app purchase in sandbox enviornment, It shows a message do you want to buy an "un known app" for 1.79. why doesnt it shows the name of the app.

Plus when i am going to upload the final binary to app store. what i need to do to swrich in app purchase from sandbox enviornment to real in app purchase or it will switch automaticall?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Probably your configuration on iTunes connect for this in app purchase is wrong, maybe you forgot to enter the name.
Go to iTunes connect, Manage you in app purchases, select the desired app, and make sure that you have all the fields correctly filled.

When you release on the app store, you don't have to do anything, the sandbox environment is just used when you are developing, when the app is uploaded to the app store, this behavior changes and you can't use your sandbox account anymore

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I added in-app purchase support to my application, I had already released a version so there was an entry in iTunes Connect.  But I've read that you need to add a new application in iTunes Connect, but check the option to upload a binary later.  Then you can enable In-App Purchase on it and configure items.

And your sandbox does not go away after the application is submitted.  The In-App Purchase system determines whether to use a sandbox based on the account that is currently logged in to the store on the device.  I think as long as you don't have a credit card (or any payment information?) associated with the account, and the account is designated as a In-App Purchase Test User in iTunes Connect, it will use the sandbox. You can log out and use a different account through the "Store" item in Settings.